How to right align comments in equations
I found today an answer on the site https://stats.stackexchange.com/ where the author wrote some kind of
$$\begin{align}
  x &= y1  ~ (I remember there is this symbol)   \text{Comment1}\\
    &= yyyyy2  ~ (I remember there is this symbol)  \text{Comment2}\\
    &= yyyyyyyyyy3  ~ (I remember there is this symbol)   \text{Comment3}\\
\end{align}$$

and all the three comments are right aligned.
Until now, what I can do is
$$\begin{align}
  x &= y1  \hspace{10cm}   \text{Comment1}\\
    &= yyyyy2  \hspace{9cm}   \text{Comment2}\\
    &= yyyyyyyyyy3  \hspace{8cm}   \text{Comment3}\\
\end{align}$$

but this is not as beautiful as theirs, because these comments are not exactly right aligned, and I need to manually set the \hspace in function of the length of y1, yyyyy2, yyyyyyyyyy3, ...
How do I right align the comments as in the first code?

See Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$?

@Werner Thank you for the suggestion. However, the Latex I used is rather for the sites Math.StackEchange and Stats.StackExchange (and not really the Latex for .tex document). And  "[  ...]" does not work on these sites.

The second & separates the columns, while the third & is the alignment point.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  y &= a x^2           &\text{Comment i}& \\
    &= a x^2 + b x     &\text{Comment ii}& \\
    &= a x^2 + b x + c &\text{Comment iii}&
\end{align}

\end{document}


Thank you very much! That's what I'm seeking (the answer of Werner is also very good).

Use either additional equations within an align by adding & as needed (also affects alignment), or use something like alignat with 2 alignment points (with an additional spacing argument).

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Original setup:
\begin{align}
  y &= a x^2           \qquad \text{Comment 1} \\
    &= a x^2 + b x     \qquad \text{Comment 2} \\
    &= a x^2 + b x + c \qquad \text{Comment 3}
\end{align}

First option:
\begin{align}
  y &= a x^2           && \text{Comment 1} \\
    &= a x^2 + b x     && \text{Comment 2} \\
    &= a x^2 + b x + c && \text{Comment 3}
\end{align}

Second option:
\begin{alignat}{2}
  y &= a x^2           &\hspace{4em}& \text{Comment 1} \\
    &= a x^2 + b x     &            & \text{Comment 2} \\
    &= a x^2 + b x + c &            & \text{Comment 3}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}

The first option also works on Stats.SE (using MathJaX):


+1 and thank you very much for the answer. However, with the both suggested solutions, it is not completely right aligned. For example, if we replace "Comment 3" by the text "Comment 3 on the line 3", the alignment is made at the first 3 letters "C" but not at the ending numbers 1, 2, 3 of the 3 comments. I remember in the answer I mentionned, the author used the symbol "~" and he obtained really the right alignment .

@NN2: Odd-numbered & symbols within the equation provides a right-alignment on the left and left-alignment on the right. The even-numbered & symbols separate the equations horizontally. With this in mind you can move the comments just after the separation, which should naturally have them all right-aligned.
